Scripting PostgreSql in Azure Pipelines with service principal
I am trying to create a custom extension that will script my PostgreSql database. I found a utility that already works.
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Connect PostgreSQL Server'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(ArmConnection)'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      echo "Generate an access token to access PostgreSQL Server."
      accessToken=$(az account get-access-token \
        --resource https://ossrdbms-aad.database.windows.net \
        --query "accessToken" \
        -o tsv)

      echo "Connecting to PostgreSQL Server..."
      az postgres flexible-server connect \
        --name '$(ServerName)' \
        --admin-user '$(AdminUserName)' \
        --admin-password $accessToken \
        --database-name '$(dbName)'

However, I want to write my extension task for easier use. I went ahead and got stuck on generating an access token. It's not entirely clear to me what I'm missing to add to the federated-token.
Unfortunately it's not clear to me what exactly should be used, as I can't really find information on that.
The goal is to generate an access token that will allow me to generate an access token to postgresql.
import tl = require('azure-pipelines-task-lib/task');
import { execSync } from 'child_process';

async function run() {
    try {
        console.log('Logging into Azure...');
        const subscription = tl.getInput('subscription', true)!;
        const serverName: string = tl.getInput('serverName', true)!;
        const adminUser: string = tl.getInput('adminUser', true)!;

        console.log("Working with subscription: " + subscription);

        const servicePrincipalId: string = tl.getEndpointAuthorizationParameter(subscription, 'serviceprincipalid', false)!;
        
        console.log("Service principal id: " + servicePrincipalId);
        
        const tenantId: string = tl.getEndpointAuthorizationParameter(subscription, 'tenantid', false)!;

        console.log("Tenant id: " + tenantId);

        const federatedTokenPath = process.env['AZURE_FEDERATED_TOKEN_FILE'];

        console.log("Federated: " + federatedTokenPath);

        // Undefined and not working
        console.log(`Reading federated token from: ${federatedTokenPath}`);
        const federatedToken = execSync(`cat ${federatedTokenPath}`, { encoding: 'utf-8' }).trim();

        process.env['AZURE_CONFIG_DIR'] = tl.getVariable('Agent.TempDirectory') || '/tmp/.azclitask';
        console.log(`Setting AZURE_CONFIG_DIR env variable to: ${process.env['AZURE_CONFIG_DIR']}`);

        console.log('Setting active cloud to: AzureCloud');
        execSync('az cloud set -n AzureCloud', { stdio: 'inherit' });

        console.log('Logging into Azure with service principal...');
        execSync(`az login --service-principal -u ${servicePrincipalId} --tenant ${tenantId} --allow-no-subscriptions --federated-token ${federatedToken}`, { stdio: 'inherit' });

        console.log(`Setting subscription to: ${subscription}`);
        execSync(`az account set --subscription ${subscription}`, { stdio: 'inherit' });

        console.log('Generating access token...');
        const accessToken = execSync(
            `az account get-access-token --resource https://ossrdbms-aad.database.windows.net --query "accessToken" -o tsv`,
            { encoding: 'utf-8' }
        ).trim();

        console.log('Access token generated.');

        console.log('Connecting to PostgreSQL Server...');
        execSync(
            `az postgres flexible-server connect --name "${serverName}" --admin-user "${adminUser}" --admin-password "${accessToken}"`,
            { stdio: 'inherit' }
        );

        console.log('Connection successful.');
       
        console.log('Clearing Azure account...');
        execSync('az account clear', { stdio: 'inherit' });

        console.log('Task completed successfully.');
    } catch (err: any) {
        tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, err.message);
    }
}

 run();

Thanks
